# VB.Net Parameter as constant inside a class inside another class

Tags: vb.net

I have a class like this:

```
Public Class ClassPermissions

    Public Class Configuration
        Public Const EditPermissions As String = "[Edit Permissions]"
        Public Const OpenConfigPanel As String = "[Open Configuration Panel]"
    End Class

    Public Class Access
        Public Const AccessCarForm As String = "[Access Car Form]"
        Public Const AccessCarList As String = "[Access Car List]"
    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Verifies permission for the logged on user
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="permissao">Permission Required, ClassPermissions.(...)</param>
    ''' <returns>True if user has permission</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function HasPermission(permission As String) As Boolean
        Dim ret As Boolean = False
        Dim sqlQuery As String = ""
        Dim dt As DataTable

        sqlQuery = "SELECT P." & permission & " FROM Permissions AS P INNER JOIN Users AS C ON P.idUser = C.UserID AND C.UserID = " & vggLoggedUserID & " AND C.Active = 1"
        dt = GetGenericDataTable(sqlQuery, "Permission")

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso dt.Rows(0)(0) = "True" Then
            ret = True
        End If

        Return ret
    End Function
End Class
```

How can i say that the parameter 'permission' of the function 'HasPermission' can only be constants that are declared inside classes that are inside the Class ClassPermissions?

What i want is, when someone is coding and writes 'ClassPermissions.HasPermission(' then it will show a list of constants, is this case 'EditPermissions', 'OpenConfigPanel', 'AccessCarForm' and 'AccessCarList'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is arguably a bad idea to expose actual column names from your database as string constants.

Declare an enum:

```
Public Enum Configuration
  EditPermissions
  OpenConfigPanel 
End Enum
```

Change your method to

```
Public Shared Function HasPermission(permission As Configuration) As Boolean
```

Inside the method make sure `permission` is defined in the enum and map it to the corresponding string value. E.g. have a `Private Dictionary(Of Configuration, String)` with the possible values and use `TryGetValue()`.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to have only one enum with all the permissions, there will be more than 100. In this case, i will have some enums, but i want to be able to choose from all of them in the function parameter